# dtale reload data cells after user input

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

I have this python script:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import dtale
#import dtale.app as dtale_app
df = pd.DataFrame([dict(firstname="cris", lastname="zane"), 
                    dict(firstname="joe",lastname="biden"), 
                    dict(firstname="kamala",lastname="harris")])


search_query = ""
print("Hi once you want to stop just enter stop")
while search_query != "stop":
    search_query = input("Enter your search query: ")
    print(search_query)
    d = dtale.show(df.loc[df["firstname"]==search_query,:],ignore_duplicates=True)
   
    print(d._url)
```

It takes user input to filter a dataframe, which is then passed into the dtale.show() method. However, the data view does not change. For example the user first searched the dataframe for joe then kamala.

```
Hi once you want to stop just enter stop
Enter your search query: joe
joe
http://Cristians-MBP:40000
Enter your search query: kamala
kamala
http://Cristians-MBP:40000
Enter your search query: kamala
kamala
http://Cristians-MBP:40000
Enter your search query:
```

But the view does not update even after refreshing and clicking reload data. The data view still shows the previous [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA2U4.png):

I believe that by setting the argument ignore_duplicates=True in the dtale.show() method should stop it from loading previously loaded data but it still does.

Comment: You should not link images of code, rather paste the code in the question which you think might be causing fault.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code to run

```
print(d._main_url)
```

instead of

```
print(d._url)
```

that should solve your problem.  "_url" is the base of the URL that D-Tale runs from.  That property should probably be renamed "_origin" rather than "_url".  "_main_url" also includes the route to the data you just loaded (EX: /dtale/main/1).

You can also run

```
dtale.instances()
```

And that will print out all the pieces of data currently loaded into D-Tale and their full URLs.